# Unexpected output using scanf() and printf() in C++

Tags: c++, printf, scanf, cout, cin

I have written the following simple code snippet:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int w, h;

    scanf("%d %d", &w, &h);

    char shop[h][w];
    for(int i=0; i<h; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
            scanf("%c", &shop[i][j]);
            //cin>>shop[i][j];

    for(int i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
            printf("%c", shop[i][j]);
            //cout<<shop[i][j];
        printf("\n");
        //cout<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On passing the input as below:

> 4 3 
>   X1S3 
>   42X4 
>   X1D2

I expect the output to be the same, because I am not modifying anything in the code.  However, when I print it, I get the following output:

> X1S 
>   3 
>   42 
>   X4 
>   X

However, on replacing `scanf()` and `printf()` with `cin` and `cout` correctly generates the required output.  Any inputs to where I might have gone wrong?

Link to code with `printf()`: http://ideone.com/NvHQUl 
Link to code with `cout`: http://ideone.com/PQWe9R

Update:  `h` denotes the number of rows; while `w` denotes the number of columns.

Comment: The output makes it pretty clear that `scanf` is reading the newlines, which `"%c"` is supposed to do.

Comment: @dxiv, yeah, changing `scanf("%c", &shop[i][j]);` to `scanf("\n%c", &shop[i][j]);` did the trick.  Please add more and change it into an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: just use fgets, not scanf, then parse the line, so much easier, and more elegant, than the black box of scanf

Comment: @self, I totally agree; but I am in the world of competitive programming, so need to use `scanf()` purely for its quickness.

Comment: is that your exact output? It'd expect a blank line before the X1S line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%c` format specifier in `scanf` reads and assigns the next character ***including*** whitespaces and newlines. Per [scanf specs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> All conversion specifiers ***other than [, c, and n*** consume and discard all leading whitespace characters (determined as if by calling isspace) before attempting to parse the input.

Therefore `scanf("%c", &shop[i][j]);` will read the newline at the end of each line of input as a regular character, and assign it to some element in the array, which explains the `printf` output.

To skip over whitespace use `scanf(" %c", &shop[i][j]);` instead (note the additional      space before `%c`).

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `scanf("%c", ...)` reads the newlines as characters.

So if your input is providing LF line breaks, for example, your 2D array ends up containing:

```
\n  X  1  S
 3 \n  4  2
 X  4 \n  X
```

And when you print it out in your loop you're basically printing:

```
"\nX1S" "\n"  <-- that's the "\n" you explicitly print after each row
"3\n42" "\n"
"X4\nX" "\n"
```

Which is, of course, the output you are seeing.